# Neo4j Lowest common ancestor

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-theory

I'm looking at using Neo4j for an organisation chart style tree where I will need to use Lowest Common Ancestor algorithms...

How can LCA be implemented on a Neo4j database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Neo4J Community` library has since version 1.8.M03 contained a `lowestCommonAncestor()` method in the [`org.neo4j.graphalgo.impl.ancestor.AncestorsUtil`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.neo4j/neo4j-graph-algo/1.8.M03/org/neo4j/graphalgo/impl/ancestor/AncestorsUtil.java?av=f) class.

Comment: can you please refer any example with it , to find LCA from DAG(directed acyclic graph)